# Testing with Espresso, asyncTask that launches an explicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-espresso

I'm making an app and its main activity has a button. When you press it, it launches an AsyncTask. This task fetches a String from the cloud (right now it gets it from my google endpoints development server) and then, on the "onPostExecute" method, launches an explicit intent to open another activity.

I wrote the following test to verify that clicking on the button actually generates the intent:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void AsyncTaskFetchesJoke() {
        onView(withId(R.id.instructions_text_view))
                .perform(click());

        intended(allOf(
                toPackage("com.example.madelenko.jokeactivity"),
                hasExtras(hasEntry(equalTo(MainActivity.JOKE), equalTo(JokeDispenser.getJoke())))
        ));

    }

}
```

Also, this is my asyncTask:

```
public class FetchJokeTask extends  AsyncTask<Context, Void, String> {
        private static MyApi myApiService = null;
        private Context context;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Context ... params) {
            if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
                MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
                // end options for devappserver

                myApiService = builder.build();
            }

            context = params[0];

            try {
                MyBean bean = myApiService.supplyJoke().execute();
                return bean.getData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, JokeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.JOKE, result);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

}
```

For some reason, my test fails and spits the following traceback:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (resolvesTo: com.example.madelenko.jokeactivity and has extras: has bundle with: key: "joke" value: "!false: it's funny because it's true.")

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:187)
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:169)
at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.ApplicationTest.AsyncTaskFetchesJoke(ApplicationTest.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.
```

Can you help me to understand why?

Thank you very much.